# Simmetrical blank space using \dotsb, or \cdots or other symbols

Tags: symbols, amsmath, packages, amssymb

Although my question is elementary, I still ask it. I'm using this code, but the situation remains the same if I use the `newtxmath`, or `mtpro2[lite]` packages, I have more space to the right of the bracket `]` and less space to the left `[`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$[\cdots,\cdots]$, $[\dotsb,\dotsb]$
\end{document}
```

*Is there a canonical problem with the my code  or for the binary symbols or I should use another (symmetrical) symbols?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no "canonical problem" with your code.

I take it that you wish to generate symmetrically-distributed whitespace around `\cdots`, both before and after the comma.

The following answer depends on the assumption that the `amsmath` package is loaded, as is the case in your MWE. With `amsmath` loaded, `\cdots` behaves like `\dotsb`, so the following solution uses only `\cdots`. I believe that there are two separate solutions to your formatting requirement: Either with symmetric whitespace, or without any whitespace at all -- which is also symmetrical, naturally. The second solution relies on the fact that, by encasing `\cdots` and `,` in curly braces, their status switches to `math-ord`. TeX does not insert whitespace between objects to type `math-ord`.

[image]

*Addendum*: if the `amsmath` package is *not* loaded, the typeset version of `$[\cdots,\cdots]$` is also symmetrical -- slightly wider than `$[{\cdots}{,}{\cdots}]$`, but not quite as wide as `$[{}\cdots{}{,}{}\cdots{}]$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$[\cdots,\cdots]$ --- asymmetric whitespace

$[{}\cdots{}{,}{}\cdots{}]$ --- symmetric whitespace

$[{\cdots}{,}{\cdots}]$ \ \ --- no whitespace
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the meantime, it is right to say my thanks for your patience and your elegant response. I thought that you didn't use the symbol controls correctly, and that's why I asked if it would be appropriate to use other symbols. Thank you very much. The answer is obviously accepted plus +1.